# An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.ni.dll (same as before even after net connection)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

```
public partial class Page2 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public Page2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }
        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List transactionList = new List();
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("URI"));
            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (Object senders, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs es) =>
            {
                string json_arr = es.Result;
                /*the above statement throws the following exception.
"An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code"*/
                if (es.Error == null)
                {
                    JArray jsonarray = JArray.Parse(json_arr);
                    for (int i = 0; i ("str1");
                        String str2= jsonarray[i].Value("str2");
                        String str3= jsonarray[i].Value("str3");
                        String str4= jsonarray[i].Value("str4");
                        String str5= jsonarray[i].Value("str5");
                        transactionList.Add(new name(str1,str2,str3,str4,str5));
                    }
                    TransactionList.ItemsSource = transactionList;
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: same problem as before even when I am connected to Internet without proxy. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: I went through details and found it here "System.net.WebException". Now what should I do to handle this exception.

Comment: What is the error text and status code?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Do let me know if this is not something you need

Comment: I was referring to the inner exception's status code and text.

Comment: {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

Comment: Are you sure the URL exists?

Comment: I had same problem before. Just check whether your internet connection is working  or not in Device/Emulator?

Comment: yes the uri exist as I opened it in the browser @Patrick Hofman

Comment: Can you post the URL? Or change it to `http://google.com` and check whether it works?

Comment: Its a JSON link and of pvt server thus cannot be shared. And how am I going to fetch data of google in my variables?